# React-Native Google Map is working in Simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have integrated google map in react-native. It is working fine in Simulator but it is getting crash in Device.

Comment: What have you tried. Add some codes and logcat errors.

Comment: I am not getting any crash log

Comment: When your apps crash, you can see through the android studio logcat the errors

Comment: It is crashing on iOS, working fine on Android.

Comment: Add your code when you add the map